# Show $\sup\{x_k : k \ge n\}$ and $\inf\{x_k : k \ge n\}$ are monotone, where $\{x_k\}$ is bounded.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $\{x_n\}$ be a bounded sequence of real numbers. Let us define
$y_n = \sup\{x_k : k \ge n\}$ and $z_n = \inf\{x_k : k \ge n\}$.
Show that the sequence $\{y_n\}$ is decreasing and $\{z_n\}$ is increasing.

Comment: Please, show us what you tried and where you are stuck

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is obvious that $ \inf(a, b)\leqslant b $, so for all $ k\in\mathbb{N} $ we have
$$
\inf(x_{k+1}, x_{k+2}, \dots)=\inf(x_{k+1}, \inf(x_{k+2}, x_{k+3}, \dots))\leqslant \inf(x_{k+2}, x_{k+3}, \dots),
$$
which implies $ \inf\{x_{k}:k\geqslant n\} $ is increasing. Using this method we can have that $ \sup\{x_{k}:k\geqslant n\} $ is decreasing.

Comment: please can you tell how to use this method to prove that yn is decreasing?

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer:

$(x_n)$ is bounded;

$y_n:=\sup \{x_k: k\ge n \}$ exists and is decreasing .

$y_{n+1}=\sup \{x_k: k\ge (n+1)\};$

1) $x_n \le x_{n+1};$

Then

$ y_{n}= \sup \{x_k: k\ge n\} =  \sup \{x_k: k\ge n+1\} =y_{n+1};$

2) $x_n > x_{n+1};$

Then

$y_{n+1}=\sup \{ x_k : k \ge n+1\} \le \sup \{x_k: k \ge n\}=y_n;$